# Observable Rx Scala behavior

Tags: scala, reactive-programming

In the following example which is from one of the books that I'm currently reading about Observables:

```
object ObservablesCreate extends App {
  val vms = Observable.create[String] { obs =>
￼￼￼￼    obs.onNext("JVM")
    obs.onNext("DartVM")
    obs.onNext("V8")
    obs.onCompleted()
    Subscription()
  }
  vms.subscribe(log _, e => log(s"oops - $e"), () => log("Done!"))
}
```

The text that follows hints that the above code snippet has a synchronous subscribe method which is very much understandable. My question is that isn't the whole purpose of using Observables to do asynchronous event emitting? I mean here is does not differ to an Iterable. Is this explained for the sake of some explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is only for the sake of explaining the `create` factory method. In the snippet you are generating the elements synchronously when a subscriber subscribe.

But in the same way you can call `onNext` asynchronously, for example when a `Future` resolves:

```
object ObservablesCreate extends App {
    def future: Future[String] = ???
    val vms = Observable.create[String] { obs =>
        val f = future
        f onComplete {
            case Success(s) => {
                obs.onNext(s)
                obs.onCompleted()
            }
            case Failure(exception) => obs.onError(exception)
        }

        Subscription()
    }

    vms.subscribe(log _, e => log(s"oops - $e"), () => log("Done!"))
}
```

(For this specific case however is much better to use the `Observable.from` method to convert a `Future` to an `Observable`)